# PowerBI 'Disabling cross highlighting/filtering by default' button in Query Reduction is not working

Tags: powerbi

I am having trouble with the 'Disabling cross highlighting/filtering by default' button in Query Reduction. It was working fine and now suddenly its not and I am able to cross highlight visualizations. Has anyone ever encountered this issue and found a solution to it.

Thank you for your help!

[Query reduction not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlBs3.png)

I tried deleting some content and reducing the file size but unfortunately didn't work.